# Audio Video Session Protocol SIP/RTP/RTCP/RTSP/H.323

Tags: networking, protocols, sip, rtp, h.323

I was exploring through the protocols.

Can someone help me to understand the differences between these protocols

SIP, RTP, RTCP, RTSP, and H.323

with reference to each other

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this URL, it answers some of your questions
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/rtsp/faq.html

Comment: The URL is really useful, but could you write at least a resume of your answer, please? Normally stackoverflow answers contain a real answer and links are used refer to the source or to further details.